# I cannot install Windows 10 on my Bootcamp partition

Tags: hard-drive, windows, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I have used Bootcamp assistant to partition my Mac mini. Then I boot up using my Windows USB drive with EFI boot. I can get to the part where I can see "Drive 1 partition3: Bootcamp" something like 600GB size.

But it cannot install Windows onto this partition. It comes up with error:

"Windows cannot be install to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks"

"Windows cannot be install to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS"

I have listed my diskutil below. I have already tried formatting my whole Mac but I receive the same error.  Please may you advise?  Thanks very much!

```
Fongs-Mac-mini:~ fongwong$ diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
  #:            TYPE NAME          SIZE    IDENTIFIER
  0:   GUID_partition_scheme            *1.0 TB   disk0
  1:            EFI EFI           209.7 MB  disk0s1
  2:         Apple_APFS Container disk2     351.0 GB  disk0s2
  3:    Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP        649.0 GB  disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
  #:            TYPE NAME          SIZE    IDENTIFIER
  0:   FDisk_partition_scheme            *2.0 TB   disk1
  1:        Windows_NTFS exFAT          2.0 TB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
  #:            TYPE NAME          SIZE    IDENTIFIER
  0:   APFS Container Scheme -           +351.0 GB  disk2
                 Physical Store disk0s2
  1:        APFS Volume macOS          26.9 GB  disk2s1
  2:        APFS Volume Preboot         28.6 MB  disk2s2
  3:        APFS Volume Recovery        516.2 MB  disk2s3
  4:        APFS Volume VM           3.2 GB   disk2s4
```

Comment: The drive where you are trying to install Windows is hybrid partitioned. This is where macOS see the drive as using a `GUID_partition_scheme`, but Windows see the same drive as using a `FDisk_partition_scheme`.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, but how do I resolve? I had Bootcamp with Windows installed before on this mac.
I have 2 internal drives:
1 drive is internal 1TB SSD which contains the Mac OS and where I wish to partition and install Bootcamp.
2nd drive an internal 2TB HDD which is formatted to exFat (this is used for storage so I can access data on both OS's)
May you advise? Thanks!

Comment: When booting to the Mac Startup Manager, where you given the option to boot the USB Windows installer from an external drive icon labeled "Windows"?

Comment: Yes, I get the option to boot from either "Windows" or "EFI".
But nothing happens when I click the "Windows" icon. The screen just freezes.

Comment: What year Mac mini? Did the Boot Camp Assistant installed on the Mac mini make the flash drive? Did you modify the Boot Camp Assistant in any way?

Comment: It is late 2012 Mac mini. 
No, the Boot Camp assistant did not create the flash drive, because it kept saying there wasn't enough space (I am using High Sierra). So I created my own bootable Windows 10 flash drive (I already have Windows bootcamp drivers that I downloaded several years ago when I used an older mac OS).
No, I didn't modify the Boot Camp assistant.

Comment: Is the `$WinPEDriver$` folder in the root directory on the flash drive? Are you sure the Windows Support Software is for your Mac and is for a Windows 10 installation? To be safe, you could try using a Boot Camp Assistant to just download the latest version of the Windows Support Software.

Comment: Oh I just checked. That particular flash drive (created manually on Windows computer) that boots with Windows and EFI option doesn't have the $WinPEDriver$ folder nor does it have the Windows support software.
However, I have a different older flash drive I recall was created in an older version of macOS using Boot camp assistant, and this one does contain the $WinPEDriver$ and Windows support software.
But the problem is this one doesn't boot at all! It doesn't show the Windows or EFI boot option. I am sure it previously did boot before so not sure what has changed :(

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson do you have any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Windows Support Software for your model Mac and a Windows 10 ISO file downloaded from Microsoft, then you can create a bootable Windows 10 USB flash drive installer without using the Boot Camp Assistant. The steps are given below.

1. Use Disk Utility to erase and ExFAT format the USB flash drive. Choose the Master Boot Record Scheme.
2. Mount the Windows 10 ISO file and the use the Finder application to copy all the files to the flash drive.
3. Use the Finder application to copy the Window Support Software to the flash drive. If you do this correctly, then the `$WinPEDriver$` and `BootCamp` folders should appear in the root folder of the ExFat formatted volume on the flash drive. For you model Mac, there should also be an `AutoUnattend.xml` file in the root folder of the ExFat formatted volume on the flash drive. If you are not sure the Windows Support Software is for your Mac, then use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the files.

If you use the Mac Startup Manager, then you should choose the icon labeled Windows to BIOS boot from the flash drive. The message below occurred because you EFI booted from the flash drive.

> "Windows cannot be install to this disk. The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks"

The message below occurred because the partition labeled BOOTCAMP was not NTFS formatted.

> "Windows cannot be install to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS"

You can NTFS format the partition labeled BOOTCAMP by highlighting the partition, then selecting the Format button. The BOOTCAMP label will disappear after formatting. This BOOTCAMP label will reappear later after installing Boot Camp.

---

Finally, I should point out that not all releases of Windows 10 have been compatible with every Mac model that Apple officially states are capable of running Windows 10. If you are have problems with installing or using a certain release, the try a different release.